# Why does shp2pgsql generate a MultiPolygon from a Polygon shapefile?

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I created a shapefile with a single Polygon in it using QGIS. When I test it with ogrinfo it says it is of type "Polygon". When I convert to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr it also comes out as Polygon. But when I use shp2pgsql it comes out as a MultiPolygon. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles have no metadata to tell `shp2psql` if they contain a polygon or a multipolygon so it "promotes" all of the polygons to multipolygons as postgis only allows a column to be one or the other.

I think `ogrinfo` will return polygon for shapefiles which contain multipolygons. While geojson does not care and will store any random string in the geometry attribute.

Comment: Ogrinfo reports polygon for a layer of a shapefile and real geometry (polygon/multipolygon) for each feature. It is a common practise to use geometry constraint in PostGIS but it does also support a generic "geometry" that can store all kind of geometries.